# How to compare comma separated ids on left join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I want to get the count of cases which are there for other tale in a format of comma separated

I have a table like below

Table1

```
id        name
1         a
2         b
3         c
4         d
5         e
6         f
```

Table2

```
id       table1_ids   user_id
1        1,2,3,4,5    1
2        1,2,3        2
3        1,2,3,4,5    1
4        1,2,3,4      2
```

When i join them, i want to display the count of table_ids in table2 like below

```
 Expected:        a-4  b-4  c-4  d-3  e-5  f-0
 Getting output:  a-4  b-4  c-4
```

I have tried query like below using laravel raw query

```
DB::select('select t1.name, t1.id, count(t2.id) as count
    from table1 as t1
    left join table2 as t2 on FIND_IN_SET(t1.id, t2.table1_ids)>0
    where t2.user_id in ('1,2')
    group By t1.name, t1.id');
```

Please suggest me how can i acheive this

Comment: That's why there is a thing called database normalization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization. Take a look at 1NF.

Comment: It seems a bit odd to be _left_ joining the way you are, but the first problem I notice is `t2.user_id IN ('1,2')` will _always_ be false as there is no user_id = '1,2' (you need to remove the quotes). But that makes me wonder how you got any results with that query... that where condition turns it into an inner join with no matches. On the other hand, those single quotes around 1,2 are stopping and starting your php string, so who knows what is really ending up in there.

Comment: You should just fix table_2. Comma separated data like that is very bad. You don't have to, but you are making your life hard by leaving it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table2` is outer joined but the condition `table2.user_id IN (...)` inside the where clause changes the query to an inner join. Move the condition from `WHERE` to `ON` clause:

```
select t1.name, t1.id, count(t2.id) as count
from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2 on
  find_in_set(t1.id, t2.table1_ids) > 0 and
  t2.user_id in (1, 2)
group by t1.name, t1.id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/045909/6)

PS: `WHERE 1 IN ('1,2')` attempts to convert `'1,2'` to a number and thus matches 1.

Answer (score 0):

I am probably going to hate myself for this but this could work:

```
select
    t1.name,
    t1.id,
    count(t2.id) as count
from
    table1 as t1
left join
    table2 as t2 on
        (
            -- We need to account for all of the variations of finding t1.id in the comma-separated field
            t2.table1_ids = t1.id or -- exactly this ID
            t2.table1_ids LIKE concat( t1.id, ',%' ) or -- starts with this ID
            t2.table1_ids LIKE concat( '%,', t1.id ) or -- ends with this ID
            t2.table1_ids LIKE concat( '%,', t1.id, ',%' ) -- the ID is found between two commas
        )
where
    t2.user_id in (1,2)
group By
    t1.name, t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Like a commenter suggested, should avoid adding comma separated data in table2 as it's bad practice.

However, that being said, you can use Laravel's Query Builder to build up your query to be more readable and cleaner. Building upon Salman A's point on changing the WHERE to ON you can do it like this:

```
DB::table("table1 as t1")
    ->leftJoin("table2 as t2", function($join) {
        $join->on(\DB::raw("find_in_set(t1.id, t2.table1_ids) > 0 and t2.user_id in (1, 2)"), \DB::raw(""), \DB::raw(""));
    })
    ->select("t1.name", "t1.id", \DB::raw("count(t2.id) as count"))
    ->groupBy("t1.name", "t1.id")
    ->get();
```